# How do I specify a CustomView Layout in the Android ActionBar Style?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I currently follow the procedure below when applying CustomView to an ActionBar.

```
//Activity.onCreate
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_initialize)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.setCustomView(R.layout.appbar)
}
```

However, using the same CustomView, it is a waste to use the same function for all other activities.

There is a way to put the above function into a parent activity that all activities inherit in common, but we do not want to create a parent activity just for that process.

So, what I want is to specify customview layout in style.xml.

```
<style name="CustomAppBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showCustom</item>
    <!--<item name="android:customNavigationLayout">@layout/appbar</item>-->
</style>
```

android: Both customNavigationLayout and android: layout were not what I wanted.

android: customNavigationLayout, android: layout Both properties were not what I wanted.

Even android: displayOptions are not working properly either. (I had to apply setDisplayShowCustomEnabled additionally because the custom view was not visible when applying setCustomView in the above state)

Is it impossible to apply a custom view to the action bar by just modifying the style?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom view with Action Bar, you can use the method:

```
actionBar.setCustomView(View view)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  any layout even an AppBar too. SO when you need it just call it.Look at these images [image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]